# Excessive console messages from Kafka Producer

Tags: log4j, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How do you control the console logging level of a Kafka Producer or Consumer?  I am using the Kafka 0.9 API in Scala.

Every time `send` on the `KafkaProducer` is called, the console gives output like below.  Could this indicate I do not have the `KafkaProducer` set up correctly, rather than just an issue of excessive logging?

```
17:52:21.236 [pool-10-thread-7] INFO  o.a.k.c.producer.ProducerConfig - ProducerConfig values: 
compression.type = none
metric.reporters = []
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
.
.
.
17:52:21.279 [pool-10-thread-7] DEBUG o.a.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bufferpool-wait-time
17:52:21.280 [pool-10-thread-7] DEBUG o.a.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name buffer-exhausted-records
17:52:21.369 [pool-10-thread-7] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(nodes = [Node(-1, localhost, 9092)], partitions = [])
17:52:21.369 [pool-10-thread-7] DEBUG o.a.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name connections-closed:client-id-producer-2
17:52:21.369 [pool-10-thread-7] DEBUG o.a.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name connections-created:client-id-producer-2
17:52:21.370 [pool-10-thread-7] DEBUG o.a.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received:client-id-producer-2
17:52:21.370 [pool-10-thread-7] DEBUG o.a.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bytes-sent:client-id-producer-2
.
.
```

There are logging configurations in the `properties` files the Kafka server and Zookeeper look at, but I've assumed these do not affect Kafka clients.  Changing some of the logging configurations in these files, and restarting the Kafka server and Zookeeper so those files are reloaded, has not solved the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correctly configuring logback solved my problem:
http://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-xml-example/

Comment: could you share exact configuration? Thanks

Comment: All I have is `log4j.properties` file for logging configuration. Any idea how can I do the configuration in this file for not printing excessive logging?

Answer (score 3):

add logger with name org.apacha.kafka on your logback.xml

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>


<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

Comment: This works for me but do you know how to get it worked for log4j.properties? I notice the NetworkClient#log is slf4j.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your client code.

> ```
>       Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
>       Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARNING);       
>       Logger.getLogger("kafka").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
> ```

Comment: My naive mistake contributed to this; producer was stored in a `def` rather than a `val`!  It was still important to reduce the logging though.  Thanks